# MathJax - aligned equations with id or class

Tags: html, mathjax

This is my first post here, so I hope everything is clear enough to understand.

I have a list of equations (written in LaTeX), which are alligned like this:

[LaTeX example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaVRJ.png)

With following code:

```
\begin{array}{rcll}
  \textrm{gravitational acceleration} & \qquad g   & = & \dfrac{G\cdot M}{R^2} \\
  \textrm{gravitational acceleration - latitude}: & \qquad g & = & g_{45} - \dfrac{1}{2}\left(g_{poles}-g_{equator}\right)\cos\left(2\varphi\cdot\dfrac{\pi}{180}\right) \\
  \textrm{gravitational acceleration - altitude}: & \qquad g_h & = & \dfrac{G\cdot M}{\left(R + h\right)^2} = g_0 \left(\dfrac{R}{R + h}\right)^2 \\
  \textrm{arc length}: & \qquad s   & = & r\theta \\
\end{array}
```

The next thing I want to do is that when I click on an equation I get a dropdown with more information or that I go to a page with information of that equation.

But to do this, I think I need some kind of ID of the equation to know which one is clicked and needs extra information.

I hope everything is clear and thanks in advance.

Comment: The (non-standard) [html extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/html.html) has \cssId{id}{math} which allows you to add ids. Is that the kind of thing you're looking for? If not, you might want to provide more information and a working code example.

Comment: I think that might be something that can work. I just tried it, but I'm not so sure how to import the extension correctly. Can you help me with this?

Comment: It works, I just added this code:

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.MathJax = {
                loader: {load: [tex]/html},
                tex: {packages: html}
            };
        </script>